Unable to load kdump crashkernel on Raspberry Pi 3B in SMP mode
This question has been moved from Stack overflow here.
I am trying to setup kdump collection infra on my Rpi 3B+ running linux kernel rpi-6.6.y cloned from official github page. I am using buildroot for rootfs.
I have enabled the following kernel configs :
CONFIG_KEXEC=y
CONFIG_SYSFS=y
CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO=y
CONFIG_CRASH_DUMP=y
CONFIG_PROC_VMCORE=y
CONFIG_PROC_KCORE=y
CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO_REDUCED=n 

and used the following command to load crashkernel image : kexec -p /Image --append="console=ttyS0,115200n8 root=/dev/nfs rw nfsroot=10.0.0.1:/home/naveen/rootfs/buildroot-arm64/,nolock,vers=4,tcp ip=10.0.0.25"
However, as soon as I trigger a kernel crash, it just hangs forever right before the crashkernel image starts booting. Why is this hanging? How can I get it working? :
# echo c > /proc/sysrq-trigger
[   22.216122] sysrq: Trigger a crash
[   22.219633] Kernel panic - not syncing: sysrq triggered crash
[   22.225465] CPU: 3 PID: 119 Comm: sh Kdump: loaded Not tainted 6.6.34-v8 #2
[   22.232533] Hardware name: Raspberry Pi 3 Model B Rev 1.2 (DT)
[   22.238448] Call trace:
[   22.240926]  dump_backtrace+0x9c/0x100
[   22.244743]  show_stack+0x20/0x38
[   22.248108]  dump_stack_lvl+0x48/0x60
[   22.251828]  dump_stack+0x18/0x28
[   22.255194]  panic+0x340/0x3b0
[   22.258300]  sysrq_handle_crash+0x24/0x30
[   22.262373]  __handle_sysrq+0xec/0x1e0
[   22.266179]  write_sysrq_trigger+0x7c/0xb0
[   22.270338]  proc_reg_write+0xa4/0x100
[   22.274149]  vfs_write+0xd0/0x318
[   22.277521]  ksys_write+0x7c/0x120
[   22.280978]  __arm64_sys_write+0x24/0x38
[   22.284966]  invoke_syscall+0x50/0x128
[   22.288779]  el0_svc_common.constprop.0+0x48/0xf0
[   22.293561]  do_el0_svc+0x24/0x38
[   22.296931]  el0_svc+0x40/0xe8
[   22.300033]  el0t_64_sync_handler+0x120/0x130
[   22.304457]  el0t_64_sync+0x190/0x198
[   22.308185] SMP: stopping secondary CPUs
[   22.312499] Starting crashdump kernel...
[   22.316474] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[   22.321152] Some CPUs may be stale, kdump will be unreliable.
[   22.326983] WARNING: CPU: 3 PID: 119 at arch/arm64/kernel/machine_kexec.c:188 machine_kexec+0x44/0x18
[   22.336439] Modules linked in:
[   22.339541] CPU: 3 PID: 119 Comm: sh Kdump: loaded Not tainted 6.6.34-v8 #2
[   22.346606] Hardware name: Raspberry Pi 3 Model B Rev 1.2 (DT)
[   22.352520] pstate: 600000c5 (nZCv daIF -PAN -UAO -TCO -DIT -SSBS BTYPE=--)
[   22.359586] pc : machine_kexec+0x44/0x1d8
[   22.363659] lr : machine_kexec+0x44/0x1d8
[   22.367731] sp : ffffffc0806539e0
[   22.371089] x29: ffffffc0806539e0 x28: ffffff8002f61e80 x27: 0000000000000000
[   22.378343] x26: 0000000000000000 x25: ffffffdc41b07d20 x24: 0000000000000063
[   22.385596] x23: 0000000000000007 x22: ffffffc080653a18 x21: ffffffdc424ab000
[   22.392848] x20: ffffff8002c21000 x19: ffffff8002c21000 x18: 0000000000000006
[   22.400100] x17: 0000000000000000 x16: 0000000000000000 x15: ffffffc0806533e0
[   22.407353] x14: 0000000000000000 x13: 2e656c6261696c65 x12: 726e75206562206c
[   22.414606] x11: 6c697720706d7564 x10: ffffffdc422fd170 x9 : ffffffdc40f3f93c
[   22.421858] x8 : 00000000ffffefff x7 : ffffffdc422fd170 x6 : 80000000fffff000
[   22.429111] x5 : ffffff80371d7bc8 x4 : 0000000000000000 x3 : 0000000000000027
[   22.436363] x2 : 0000000000000000 x1 : 0000000000000000 x0 : ffffff8002f61e80
[   22.443616] Call trace:
[   22.446092]  machine_kexec+0x44/0x1d8
[   22.449814]  __crash_kexec+0x9c/0x180
[   22.453539]  panic+0x32c/0x3b0
[   22.456642]  sysrq_handle_crash+0x24/0x30
[   22.460713]  __handle_sysrq+0xec/0x1e0
[   22.464520]  write_sysrq_trigger+0x7c/0xb0
[   22.468679]  proc_reg_write+0xa4/0x100
[   22.472490]  vfs_write+0xd0/0x318
[   22.475861]  ksys_write+0x7c/0x120
[   22.479320]  __arm64_sys_write+0x24/0x38
[   22.483307]  invoke_syscall+0x50/0x128
[   22.487119]  el0_svc_common.constprop.0+0x48/0xf0
[   22.491901]  do_el0_svc+0x24/0x38
[   22.495272]  el0_svc+0x40/0xe8
[   22.498373]  el0t_64_sync_handler+0x120/0x130
[   22.502798]  el0t_64_sync+0x190/0x198
[   22.506517] ---[ end trace 0000000000000000 ]---
[   22.511198] Bye! 

Important
Meanwhile, I also came across an article here that says that we need to turn SMP off to get a kdump. Why? Is that a known issue?
[I already checked the Issues page of rpi kernel on github and couldn't find relevant issue. I have raised one though here to which there is no response yet.]
